# highcharts div resize to min and max on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, minimize, maximize

I have a page where multiple graphs are shown for different components. I am using highcharts. Below is the code. How can I set it up so that when the user clicks on the div , it will resize that graph to the whole page and a click will bring it back to the orginal size. Basically to toggle on each click between max screen and original size using javascript or jquery.

```
 <div id="graph_id"></div>

  <div id="top_container">
    <div id="container_1" style="float:left ; height: 50%; width:32%; min-width: 200px; background:#000000; padding:5px;"></div>
    <div id="container_2"    style="float:left ; height: 50%; width:32%; min-width: 200px; background:#000000; padding:5px;"></div>
    <div id="container_3" style="float:left ; height: 50%; width:32%; min-width: 200px; background:#000000; padding:5px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All the highcharts are rendered to the containers using the code

```
 var chart_container_opt_1 = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container_1',
            .....

  var chart_1 = new Highcharts.StockChart(chart_container_opt_1);
```

and similar ones for chart_2 with container_2 and chart_3 for container_3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second solution is using `highslide` which allows to open chart in the popup.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/roadrash/GqhEX/

Answer (score 3):

You can use highchart function :-

```
chart.setSize (width,height);
```

On every click calculate the new height and width which you can easily find using jquery height() and width() functions. and after that call the above function with new parameters. 
Have a look at

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-setsize-button/